# Cannot login to Tomcat7 Admin portal

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, tomcat7

I have an Ubuntu 14.04 server with a fresh Tomcat7 installation (with management modules). I can't login to the management page no matter what user settings I use on /etc/tomcat7/tomcat-users.xml .

The current one is this:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin-script"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

I also gave all the above roles to the same user but still can't authenticate. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you're missing the parent tags in your XML.

The full XML format should be:

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Also, bounce the Tomcat service once you're done.

Comment: I do have them, just did not include them in here. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Try add `MemoryRealm` in `server.xml`:

```
<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />
...
</Engine>
```

Comment: did not work but thanks.